# Input multiple different variables from a single command line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I looking for the easiest way to input 4 different variables(add Cake 2 USD 2018-06-21) from a single command line. Maybe someone know similar app like [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)? Or it's easier to write own parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading the line in as a whole and then using some sort of format for the input using the String[.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method. Here is a example using CSV format:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private String[] takeInput() {   
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    return tokens;
}
```

> example input: add, Cake, Example
>
> return value: String[] {"add", "Cake", "Example" };